# {message: "Method addColumns does not exist.", exception: "BadMethodCallException",…}

Tags: laravel-5.5, yajra-datatable

I wanna use Yajra DataTable in laravel. but i get this error :
{message: "Method addColumns does not exist.", exception: "BadMethodCallException",…}

and this is my code :

```
    public function show(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax()){
      $searchs = $request->get('search');
      $search = $searchs['value'];
      DB::statement(\DB::raw('set @nomor = 0'));
      $index = DB::table('tb_test')->
      select([DB::raw('@nomor := @nomor + 1 as no'),
      'id',
      'name'
      ]);

      return DataTables::of($index)
           ->addColumns('action', function($index){
               $tag = "<center><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' onclick=editNewModal('".$index->id."')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Ubah</a>";
               $tag .= "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick=delNewModal('".$index->id."')><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Hapus</a></center>";
               return $tag;
           })
       ->make(true);
    }
```

can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've noticed that I forgot to do

```
    "composer dumpautoload".
```